# Emacs string-match "Compilation finished" but failed

Tags: emacs

I want to delete compilation buffer when **Compilation finished**.

Following is my init-compile.el

```
(require 'compile)

(defun notify-compilation-result(buffer msg)
  (if (string-match "Compilation finished" msg)
      (progn (delete-windows-on buffer)))
  (setq current-frame (car (car (cdr (current-frame-configuration)))))
  (select-frame-set-input-focus current-frame))

(add-to-list 'compilation-finish-functions 
             'notify-compilation-result)

(provide 'init-compile)
```

How to match the plain string?

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
(cl-search "compilation finished" "whatever compilation finished whatever")
9
(cl-search "compilation finished" "compilation did not finish")
nil
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with elisp. Just fetched an example from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand and modified. But it doesn't take any effect.

Comment: Mmm... what did you do with that code then? :) Just for the record, from how it looks, it would suggest that you save it in the file `init-compile.el` somewhere, where Emacs can find it (eval `load-path` to see all possible locations Emacs will look for, you can also add more locations there). and then in your `.emacs` file put `(require 'init-compile)`, then eval that form, if you need it for this session.

Comment: I use that function to notify the compilation result. If compile succeed, than dismiss the compilation buffer, else do nothing.

Comment: @goofansu yes, I can see what's it doing. I was asking more in terms of how have you set it up to be loaded and used. I mean, it's not enough to put this code in a file. You need to make sure it is loaded. Just to make sure it is, if you do `C-h f` `notify-compilation-result` do you get a help buffer that tells you where the file with this function lives?

Comment: Yes, `C-h f notify-compilation-result` told me that the function is in init-compile.el.

Comment: @goofansu well, ok then, try this: `C-u M-x eval-defun` while the point is in the function definition, then run the compilation where you believe this function has to trigger. If and when it will trigger, Emacs will initiate step debugger. In order to step through the function press `SPC`, when the condition in question will be tested pay close attention to what is being tested against what. (`*Messages*` buffer will have the history in case you forget).

Comment: Ok, let me try again.